# Error al subir un xml manualmente en la página de pruebas de la AEAT

Tags: aeat-sii

Estoy comenzando a conectar mi programa con el SII. Ante de comenzar con el código php he intentado subir un xml manualmente para verificar que está bien construido. Para ello he accedido con certificado a la página:
https://prewww1.aeat.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/explotacion/ws/ClienteWSAEAT2.html

He seleccionado la URL Endpoint que me ofrece en el desplegable:
***/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP***

El xml contiene una consulta de facturas emitidas (previamente he introducido una factura emitida manualmente). Es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:siiLR="https://prewww2.aeat.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii_1_1_bis/fact/ws/ConsultaLR.xsd"
    xmlns:sii="https://prewww2.aeat.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii_1_1_bis/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <siiLR:ConsultaLRFacturasEmitidas>
            <sii:Cabecera>
                <sii:IDVersionSii>1.1</sii:IDVersionSii>
                <sii:Titular>
                    <sii:NombreRazon>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</sii:NombreRazon>
                    <sii:NIF>XXXXXXXXX</sii:NIF>
                </sii:Titular>
            </sii:Cabecera>
            <siiLR:FiltroConsulta>
                <sii:PeriodoLiquidacion>
                    <sii:Ejercicio>2023</sii:Ejercicio>
                    <sii:Periodo>2T</sii:Periodo>
                </sii:PeriodoLiquidacion>
            </siiLR:FiltroConsulta>
        </siiLR:ConsultaLRFacturasEmitidas>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Las urls que apuntan las xsd las he adaptado siguiendo las indicaciones que vienen en la página de inicio del portal de pruebas.
El código xml lo he tomado del ejemplo de la última documentación técnica (v1.1 de 2022).
El Endpoint he elegido el que me ofrece el desplegable.

Con todo esto, la respuesta que me da es un error "**Error La direccion no se corresponde con el fichero de entrada.**"

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar el error?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné. Cambiando las direcciones de las xsd. Os dejo el nuevo código por si es de interés:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd"
    xmlns:ns2="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/ConsultaLR.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:ConsultaLRFacturasEmitidas>
            <ns1:Cabecera>
                <ns1:IDVersionSii>1.1</ns1:IDVersionSii>
                <ns1:Titular>
                    <ns1:NombreRazon>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:NombreRazon>
                    <ns1:NIF>XXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:NIF>
                </ns1:Titular>
            </ns1:Cabecera>
            <ns2:FiltroConsulta>
                <ns1:PeriodoLiquidacion>
                    <ns1:Ejercicio>2023</ns1:Ejercicio>
                    <ns1:Periodo>2T</ns1:Periodo>
                </ns1:PeriodoLiquidacion>
            </ns2:FiltroConsulta>
        </ns2:ConsultaLRFacturasEmitidas>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```